# Не работает код verilog: "Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at chaincounter.v(146) near text "always"; expecting "end""

Tags: verilog

я прочитал о возможности задачи task содержать в себе контроль событий, но такой код не компилируется в quartus 2

```
output [10:0] seg;
input t_clk;
input [3:0] inod;
input [3:0] indes;
input [3:0] insot;
reg [7:0] t_od,t_des,t_sot;
reg [1:0] t_cnt;
begin
    t_cnt=0;
    t_od=convert(inod);
    t_des=convert(indes);
    t_sot=convert(insot);
    always @ (posedge t_clk)
    begin
        case(t_cnt)
        2`b00 : begin 
                    seg[10:8]=3`b001;
                    seg[7:0]=t_od;
                    t_cnt=t_cnt+1;
                  end
        2`b01 : begin 
                    seg[10:8]=3`b010;
                    seg[7:0]=t_des;
                    t_cnt=t_cnt+1;
                  end
        2`b10 : begin 
                    seg[10:8]=3`b100;
                    seg[7:0]=t_sot;
                    t_cnt=2`b00;
                  end
        endcase
    end
end
endtask
```

Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at chaincounter.v(146) near text "always";  expecting "end"

на всякий случай:

```
function [7:0] convert;
input [3:0] conv_in;
begin
    case(conv_in)
    0 : convert=8`b11000000;
    1 : convert=8`b11111001;
    2 : convert=8`b10100100;
    3 : convert=8`b10110000;
    4 : convert=8`b10011001;
    5 : convert=8`b10010010;
    6 : convert=8`b10000010;
    7 : convert=8`b11111000;
    8 : convert=8`b10000000;
    9 : convert=8`b10010000;
    endcase
end
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вынести `always` за конструкцию `begin ... end`. В `verilog` есть конструкция `assign` для постоянного назначения сигналов, можно почитать [здесь](https://marsohod.org/11-blog/84-veriloglesson4).

Я не уверен в синтаксисе но мне кажется это должно выглядеть примерно так

```
output [10:0] seg;
input t_clk;
input [3:0] inod;
input [3:0] indes;
input [3:0] insot;
reg [7:0] t_od,t_des,t_sot;
reg [1:0] t_cnt;

assign t_cnt=0;
assign t_od=convert(inod);
assign t_des=convert(indes);
assign t_sot=convert(insot);

always @ (posedge t_clk)
begin
    case(t_cnt)
    2`b00 : begin 
                seg[10:8]=3`b001;
                seg[7:0]=t_od;
                t_cnt=t_cnt+1;
              end
    2`b01 : begin 
                seg[10:8]=3`b010;
                seg[7:0]=t_des;
                t_cnt=t_cnt+1;
              end
    2`b10 : begin 
                seg[10:8]=3`b100;
                seg[7:0]=t_sot;
                t_cnt=2`b00;
              end
    endcase
end
endtask
```

Comment: Попробовал, но так не работает, ошибка сохранилась.

Comment: Ошибка такая же? Не может быть потому что begin снаружи always больше нет. Я дополнил код, попробуйте еще раз пожалуйста

Comment: Не работает: near text "always";  expecting "endfunction". 
Я в проекте лучше удалю эту задачу.

Comment: ну похоже эта ошибка не связана с этим кодом, а с тем что вы какую то функцию забыли закончить `endfunction`

Answer (score 0):

Я выгреб все ошибки.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module chaincounter
(
    input             t_clk,
    input       [3:0] inod,
    input       [3:0] indes,
    input       [3:0] insot,
    output reg [10:0] seg
);

    wire [7:0] t_od, t_des, t_sot;
     reg [1:0] t_cnt; initial t_cnt = '0;

assign t_od  = convert(inod);
assign t_des = convert(indes);
assign t_sot = convert(insot);

always @(posedge t_clk)
    case(t_cnt)
    2'b00 : begin 
                seg[10:8] <= 3'b001;
                seg[7:0]  <= t_od;
                t_cnt     <= t_cnt+1;
            end
    2'b01 : begin  
                seg[10:8] <= 3'b010;
                seg[7:0]  <= t_des;
                t_cnt     <= t_cnt+1;
            end
    2'b10 : begin 
                seg[10:8] <= 3'b100;
                seg[7:0]  <= t_sot;
                t_cnt     <= 2'b00;
            end
    endcase
endmodule

function [7:0] convert;
input [3:0] conv_in;
begin
    case(conv_in)
    0 : convert <= 8'b11000000;
    1 : convert <= 8'b11111001;
    2 : convert <= 8'b10100100;
    3 : convert <= 8'b10110000;
    4 : convert <= 8'b10011001;
    5 : convert <= 8'b10010010;
    6 : convert <= 8'b10000010;
    7 : convert <= 8'b11111000;
    8 : convert <= 8'b10000000;
    9 : convert <= 8'b10010000;
    endcase
end
endfunction
```

Это тестбенч

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module TB;

    parameter  integer Fclk = 100_000_000;
    localparam real    Pclk = 1_000_000_000/Fclk;

     reg        t_clk;  initial t_clk = '1;
     reg  [3:0] inod;   initial inod  = '0;
     reg  [3:0] indes;  initial indes = '0;
     reg  [3:0] insot;  initial insot = '0;
    wire [10:0] seg;    

     reg  [5:0] tick;   initial tick  = '0;
    wire        inod_e, indes_e, insot_e;

initial forever begin #(Pclk/2) t_clk = ~t_clk; end

assign inod_e  = (tick=='1);
assign indes_e = (inod_e&(inod=='1));
assign insot_e = (inod_e&(inod=='1)&(indes=='1));

always @(posedge t_clk)                          tick  <= tick  + 1;
always @(posedge t_clk) if (inod_e)  if (inod_e) inod  <= inod  + 1;
always @(posedge t_clk) if (indes_e) if (inod_e) indes <= indes + 1;
always @(posedge t_clk) if (insot_e) if (inod_e) insot <= insot + 1;

//======================================
chaincounter
chaincounter (
    .t_clk  (   t_clk   ),
    .inod   (   inod    ), // <- [3:0]
    .indes  (   indes   ), // <- [3:0]
    .insot  (   insot   ), // <- [3:0]
    .seg    (   seg     ));// -> [10:0]
//======================================

endmodule
```